# How to make a JSONP POST request in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The $http.jsonp method described in the official documentation seems to always perform get requests: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#methods_jsonp.

I have tried setting the config option to 'POST' but it still sends a GET:

```
$http.jsonp('/api/new?callback=JSON_CALLBACK', {method: 'POST'});
```

I have also tried setting a data argument in the hope that angular would switch to a POST:

```
$http.jsonp('/api/new?callback=JSON_CALLBACK', {data: {stuff: true}});
```

But it still doesn't :)

As for making a post like this:

```
$http.post('/api/new?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
```

It does make a POST obviously but doesn't do the angular magic thingy with the JSON_CALLBACK and produces the following JS error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xxx.yyy.zzz' is therefore not allowed access.
```

(The API is not on the same server as the app, that's the point of JSONP).

Google was most unhelpful on this issue and reading through angular's sources is not the easiest task. So how can I make a JSONP POST request with angular?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You cannot make a POST request using JSON-P (with or without Angular)

A JSON-P request works by generating a `<script>` element with a `src` attribute. This will always trigger a GET request.

---

If you want to make a cross-domain POST request with JavaScript then you must use either XMLHttpRequest (and have the server supply suitable access control headers as per [the CORS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)) or proxy the request through the server hosting the page.

Comment: Damn it, of course! Thank you, accepting this as soon as I'm allowed to.

Comment: thats only half of the story I guess, .. IMO it is possible using POST and JSON-P together. But as you already noticed it might not work when doing it through cross-domains. but same domain?! (anyway angular does not seem to support it locally)

Comment: @OleK — No, that is the whole story. See again the very first sentence. It is impossible to make a POST request using JSONP. The second paragraph of the answer explains why that is.

Comment: So the XMLHttpRequest determines its a JSON-P? But what if I have an xhr with the benifit of the (?)&callback=? parameter and POST data? Like I do with jquery. Example: http://imgur.com/IQw8J1S and the response http://imgur.com/YgbX89T

Comment: OK, you can fetch JSON-P data manually with XHR and then process it manually, but that throws in a whole lot of complications with how you have to handle the data for no benefit over JSON.

Comment: Right, just want to mention it is possible through jquery while angularjs does not allow post requests for jsonp. THanks