# AngularJS JSON POST

Tags: json, angularjs, jsonp

I'm trying to use the Twitch API found here: https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API and they mention that "`All API methods support JSON-P by providing a callback parameter with the request.`" I'm using angularJS and after doing some research, I have discovered that it's not possible to make POST requests using JSONP calls([How to make a JSONP POST request in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352127/how-to-make-a-jsonp-post-request-in-angular)).

There's an authentication part of the API that is asking me to do this:

```
Step 3:On your server, you can now make the following request to obtain an access token:

POST https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token

POST Body (URL-encoded)

client_id=[your client ID]
&client_secret=[your client secret]
&grant_type=authorization_code
&redirect_uri=[your registered redirect URI]
&code=[code received from redirect URI]

Step 4. We'll respond with a JSON-encoded access token...
```

How am I supposed to make  a POST request using JSONP if it's not possible??
What am I missing?

Comment: The post request has to be made from server not from client. You would not want to give away the clientid\secret so this has to be done on server.

Comment: Does this mean I should be calling a PHP script to do it for me? I think I might not understand the difference.

Comment: yes on the server using what ever server platform you are using like php

Answer (score 0):

This POST request doesn't use JSONP.  It's just a POST request that you need to send from your server to the twitch url they provide.

If you look at the url they provide, you will see it's not passing anything, thus it can't be JSONP.

If you look in step 1, they have you send them here:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/authorize
    ?response_type=code
    &client_id=[your client ID]
    &redirect_uri=[your registered redirect URI]
    &scope=[space separated list of scopes]
```

This would be your JSONP request.

Once they do that your server has to get their token with the regular POST and the body as they specify in the docs.