# angularjs cannnot use $http.jsonp for send POST method

Tags: php, angularjs, json

Please, We have been using a lort of examples but none of them send by post method.

We have a lot of services in angularjs posting like this:

```
            $http.post(url + '/login.php?action=login_user', data).success(function(response, status) {
                callback(response, status);
            }).error(function(response, status) {
                callback(response, status);
            });
```

Where data allways are JSON data like this or more complex:

```
            var data = {
                username: username,
                password: password
            };
```

And we need adap a lot of this calls to a JSONP with the minimum change soo try send data by post as JSON like previos but changing to this (using jsonp)

```
            $http.jsonp(url + '/login.php?action=login_user&callback=JSON_CALLBACK', data).success(function(response, status) {
                callback(response, status);
            }).error(function(response, status) {
                callback(response, status);
            });
```

But looking the inspector this is not sending the post JSON data. Why?

Is because $http.jsonp never use POST and only GET method? How can We send our json data object by POST ?

We use PHP in the server, We never see an full example using angularjs sending JSONP by post to PHP and we dont know how get the the posting vals in PHP.

So in PHP We send a JSON but using the JSONP in angular how must We send form PHP to Angularjs.

Our Web currently is working OK but is not using JSONP in AngularJS but now We need change all for usin JSONP.

A full simple example with the call from AngularJS and how PH get the post and send JSON would help us a lot because after searching a lot we do not find.

Please, thanks in advance and hope this can help other

Comment: You can't make post with JsonP, only gets, look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352127/how-to-make-a-jsonp-post-request-in-angular.

Comment: why don't you use http this way ? : $http({method:'POST',url:'url',data:data}).success().error(); You can send whatever you want in data, json or not json...

Comment: Answer to Julo0sS, we currently use POST and all is ok but we need use JSONP method because  last-minute changes force us to cross domain. Our web is in diferent domain of aour PHP server, that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think this will suit you better - a simple post method in AngularJS

```
$scope.Executenowbuttons = function () {
    // $scope.datetimess = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm ');
    // console.log(datetimess);
    // alert($scope.today);
    var pullDataUrl = 'http://192.168.1.20:8082/resources/scheduleExecuteJob/scheduleExecuteJob';
    var pullData = {
        "execprogms": "DEDUP",
        "delid": "",
        // "datimevalue": "18-Jul-2017 12:20",
        "datimevalue": $scope.datetimes,
        "userName": "admin"
    };
    $http.post(pullDataUrl, pullData)
        .success(function (data) {
            var msg;
            alert(data.msg)
                // location.reload();
                //$location.path('/Importer/Merge')
                //$scope.getAllDatatreeView();
        })
        .error(function () {
            alert("Session Time out")
        });
};
```